# sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA key; from agent: agent refused operation

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring, ssh-keygen

I have a new machine running debian sid on which I generated a new ssh key-pair. I wanted to find a convenient way to copy this new key-pair to various other machines using my old Ubuntu machine and its key-pair. I have disabled password logins for all the "remote" machines, so I wanted to use the old machine as an intermediate. While researching this, I found the exact situation given [as an example in the manual page for `ssh-copy-id`.](https://www.mankier.com/1/ssh-copy-id#Examples) I followed the example to access a pi zero running `pihole`, but got the error in the post title.

To sum up my steps from that example, where `debian` is the machine with the new key-pair, `sarp.lan` is the machine with the old key-pair and `pihole` is the "remote" machine, I did:
[image]

However, running `ssh -v pihole`, I do see the output

```
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/sarp/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:V74Y4EhlszaIzco6oxOtl86ALj/U8rhXO2XUpEftZLU agent
```

I read through various posts on this topic, but none of the solutions worked for me. Here are some details/things I have tried:

- Permissions are correct for `.ssh/`[image]
- I am not running gnome-keyring-daemon:
  `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` returns `/tmp/ssh-a8Ol5O0XY9Fv/agent.1326`, and I don't see the keyring daemon running through `ps aux`.
- `ssh-add -l` correctly displays the two keys as can be see in the first picture (one from the old machine, the other from the new machine)
- I just copied the `.ssh/config` from the old machine, so the hostname/username/etc. should be fine.

Let me know if I should provide additional useful info, and apologies if it is something very obvious, but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 20):

Make sure the permissions of the key directory and keys are correct on the client.
The ~/.ssh directory should only have execute, read and write permissions for the user. If not then change them:

User can execute, read and write

`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

For the private keys and also the id_rsa, user can read and write

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

For the public keys, user can read and write, others can read

`chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think the permissions in the picture should be alright tho?

Comment: In my case, permissions caused the very same error message and the answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

When the issue is not access rights below `~/.ssh` (as your detailed listing indicates), another option might be that the authentication agent is somehow hanging.

Since the authentication daemon should automatically spawn if gone, you can simply try killing it, e.g. with `killall ssh-agent`.

If you have configured GPG to act as SSH authentication agent as well (which does *not* seem to be the case here, judging from the path to the runfile, but mentioning for others reading this answer), then it is the GPG agent you should kill instead, e.g. with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like other folks missed the fact that access rights was not the issue.

Comment: I am happy that it seems I understood you.  If you think not only that but also that my answer is correct, then please mark it as such. I certainly hope that you have solved your concrete problem by now so it might be impossible to know for sure what exactly would be the correct answer, so might just be an educated guess...

Comment: Yeah, for that exact reason  of not even remembering what the issue was, I won't mark it as solved, but thank you regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA ...` message usually means that your private key can't be read, either because of a permissions problem or because it can't be unlocked.

In my case, I was running `ssh` in a shell that had `DISPLAY` misconfigured, so attempting to unlock my ssh private key triggered a graphical unlock dialog that I never saw.  Fixing `DISPLAY` or explicitly unlocking my private key with `ssh-add` fixed my particular case.